# Elevation of entire Electron app / Mounting to /Volumes on MacOS Sierra

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

First time question poster but long time user.

I'm currently writing an Electron app that runs on Windows and OSX/MacOS. This app has a portion of it that mounts network locations using SMB protocol on Windows and SMB, AFP, NFS protocols on OSX/MacOS.

When you mount network locations through the MacOS UI (Finder | Go |Connect To Server) these mounts end up in the /Volumes folder. Mounts going to the /Volumes folder has been the norm for many versions of OSX/MacOS. The wrinkle recently introduced is that under Sierra you no longer can mount to /Volumes programmatically or through command line (Terminal) without elevating to create your mount point ("mkdir") and mounting ("mount").

This program has a use case where users frequently mount network shares and they need to be in /Volumes because the most commonly used video editing packages look there by default.

I've tried some of the sudo related packages (sudo, electron-sudo, sudo prompt) to elevate my mount related commands on an as needed basis. The client would prefer if I elevate once on startup of the app and then never ask again.

So my question is: **does anyone have experience in elevating a whole electron app on startup, complete with native OSX/MacOS GUI elevation prompt (not Terminal elevation prompt) OR do you know how to bypass the need for elevation when creating mount points (folders) under /Volumes and then mounting there in Sierra forward?**

Thanks in advance.